# aws cli: invalid security token

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface

I'm trying to create a reusable delegation set to use as whitelisted nameservers for my domains, using aws cli on Mac OS X. My AWS credentials (those of an IAM profile I created for that purpose with full administrator privileges, an location set to us-east-1) were correctly entered during setup and accepted by the system.

When entering the command

```
$ aws route53 create-reusable-delegation-set --caller-reference [CALLER-REFERENCE] --hosted-zone-id [HOSTED_ZONE] --generate-cli-skeleton
```

the request is successful and I get the response:

```
{
    "CallerReference": "", 
    "HostedZoneId": ""
}
```

But when I remove --generate-cli-skeleton and enter

```
aws route53 create-reusable-delegation-set --caller-reference [CALLER-REFERENCE] --hosted-zone-id [HOSTED_ZONE]
```

I get this:

```
An error occurred (InvalidClientTokenId) when calling the CreateReusableDelegationSet operation: The security token included in the request is invalid.
```

I reality, my IAM credentials, despite being valid, and despite the profile I am using (donaldjenkins) having full administrator privileges, are refused systematically in all aws services and for all commands, not just Route53.

I've been unable to pinpoint the cause of this despite extensive research. Any suggestions gratefully receieved.

Comment: I don't know where we'd start with this -- have you talked to AWS support?

Comment: Check if your local system's clock is out of sync. Check that you have the latest AWS CLI tool installed.

Comment: @ChristianTernus: Yes, I've sent support ticket to AWS.

Comment: @MarkB: I had spotted the local system's clock being out of sync as a possible cause when researching the issue. But my Mac system clock is updated using time.apple.com and isn't out of sync.  It also occurred to me that since I shuttle between New York and Paris a lot that might be the reason—but experimenting with VPN and AWS locations in various combinations didn't work either.

Answer (score 8):

Deleting my credentials file (Linux, macOS, or Unix: `~/.aws`  Windows: `%UserProfile%\.aws`) then running `aws configure` again worked for me

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to delete existing credentials for the IAM user and issue new ones.  For some reason the credentials recorded during the initial setup of aws cli never worked properly, but overwriting them with new ones removed the issue instantly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact issue.
I'm running NodeJS on my local environment, and trying to deploy to Amazon using code deploy and some other aws tools.

What worked for me was to delete the current config and credentials folder, regnerate a new key and use. THis was after i originally installed aws cli and added the keys, had to add the keys again.

Depending on your folder structure, navigate to your home directory.
On mac if you open a new terminal, it should show your current home directory:  "/Users/YOURNAME"

```
cd .aws
rm -rf config
rm -rf credentials
```

After you do this, go back to your home directory, then run:

```
"aws configure".
```

Enter your Key and secret key.

You can find more details here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html#cli-quick-configuration under Quickly Configuring the AWS CLI